# Java EE JPA 2 Entity Mappings

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have a MySQL database with the following:

```
`title` text,
`content` longtext,
```

and have them mapped to the following Entity attributes:

```
private String title;
private String content;
```

Here are my questions:

1. When entering a value, does the JPA automatically detect the size of text and longtext, or do I have to annotate the attributes with @Column(length...)?
2. I have seen people using the @Lob annotation on strings. In this case would it be suitable to use it (and on which attributes)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add column attributes has only sense for varchar/char fields. Text/longtext couldn't be optimized by explicit length spec.
2. Use @Lob for both fields

Answer (score 0):

`text` datatype of MySQL is actually an LOB, or better say CLOB (character strings or LOB). So, yes it would be very much suitable to annotate it using `@Lob`.